# Not able to run intern functional tests. Error: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, intern, leadfoot

Having node 0.12 and intern 3. Trying to run intern based functional tests gives following error:

```
 SUITE ERROR
 Error: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
   at Server.createSession           <node_modules/intern/node_modules/leadfoot/Server.js:307:15>
  at <node_modules/intern/lib/executors/Runner.js:174:22>
  at retry  <node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:695:13>
  at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:393:15>
  at runCallbacks  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:11:11>
  at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:317:4>
  at run  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:237:7>
  at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/nextTick.ts:44:3>
  at process._tickCallback  <node.js:355:11>
```

Nothing is running on port 4444 too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not using a service like BrowserStack, you need to start Selenium (`selenium-server-standalone-xxx.jar`) or a standalone WebDriver server (e.g., chromedriver) before running `intern-runner`.

Comment: Even after starting selenium standalone server, same exception is thrown

Comment: Are you starting Selenium on the same system that you're running Intern on (you should be)? Do you see any an error messages in the Selenium console when Intern tries to connect?

Comment: Yes.. Able to start selenium successfully on my local system. And no error messages are generated on Selenium console.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. Had made changes to /etc/hosts file. Reverted it to use 127.0.0.1 localhost and that resolved the error.